# How to enable virtualization Acer aspire e1-531

Tags: virtualization, bios, acer

I'm trying to enable virtualization for genymotion on my Acer aspire e1-531. It doesn't have the advance option in bios and all solutions I've seen are for Windows

#### Result of `lscpu`

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          2
On-line CPU(s) list:             0,1
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              2
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           42
Model name:                      Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU B960 @ 2.20GHz
Stepping:                        7
CPU MHz:                         1315.882
CPU max MHz:                     2200.0000
CPU min MHz:                     800.0000
BogoMIPS:                        4390.01
L1d cache:                       64 KiB
L1i cache:                       64 KiB
L2 cache:                        512 KiB
L3 cache:                        2 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0,1
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: VMX unsupported
Vulnerability L1tf:              Mitigation; PTE Inversion
Vulnerability Mds:               Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT disabled
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Mitigation; PTI
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled v
                                 ia prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user
                                  pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Full generic retpoline, IBPB condit
                                 ional, IBRS_FW, STIBP disabled, RSB filling
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtr
                                 r pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx f
                                 xsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm con
                                 stant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl x
                                 topology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmu
                                 lqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 x
                                 tpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_d
                                 eadline_timer xsave lahf_lm epb pti ssbd ibrs i
                                 bpb stibp xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts md_clear
                                  flush_l1d
```

Comment: Please add the output of `lscpu` to the question by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1353957/edit) it.

Comment: I had just done that

Answer (score 5):

According to your `lscpu` output:

> ... VMX unsupported

and official information from Intel web-site your Pentium B960 [does not support](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/59836/intel-pentium-processor-b960-2m-cache-2-20-ghz.html) *Intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x)*.

So you can use only software virtualization in VirtualBox which is really slow.

Comment: Unfortunately Intel cripples functionality on their cheapest CPUs, not just performance. :/  Definitely something to keep in mind when shopping for anything lower-end than an i3, i.e. Pentium/Celeron.  e.g. before Ice Lake, when the mainstream CPUs have AVX2, the budget CPUs are only half width and don't support AVX or even BMI1/2.  (e.g. Comet Lake Pentium G6405 launched Q1 2021 in that sorry state: https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/products/sku/201901/intel-pentium-gold-g6405-processor-4m-cache-4-10-ghz/specifications.html).  Fortunately Intel isn't the only budget x86 vendor...